# How to cause core data to dealloc the memory after deleting an object?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Step 1: I open a document

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName = @"MyDocument";
NSURL *url = [documentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url.path];
if (fileExists) {
    [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {[self documentOpened:success];}];

}else{
    [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){[self documentOpened:success];}];
}
```

...

```
-(void)documentOpened:(BOOL)success
{
    NSLog(@"Document opened");
    if (success)
    {
        if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)
        {
            self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
            [self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
           // [self loadGames];
        }
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"Fail to open file");
    }
}
```

step 2: I fetch an object

```
+(Game*) gameWithDate:(NSDate*)date
           inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    Game* res;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Game"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error      ];
    if(!matches || error || [matches count] > 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: NO Game in DB");
    }else
    {
        if ([matches count])
        {
            res = [matches firstObject];
            NSLog(@"Fetching existing game");
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Creating a game");
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

step 3: I delete the object:

```
Game *g = [Game gameWithDate:lastDate inContext:managedObjectContext];
[managedObjectContext deleteObject:g];
g = nil;
```

The Game objects are about 20[Mbyte].
After performing step 3 I noted that the memory allocated in step 2 (by core data) didn't got released after step 3. If I perform steps 2 and 3 in a loop, the memory keep getting allocated but never released.

I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html) that it could be the undo manager keeping this memory alive so I shut it down (in step 1) but it didn't help.
I tried:

```
[managedObjectContext refreshObject:g mergeChanges:NO];
```

or:

```
[managedObjectContext reset];
```

right after step 3. The memory got deallocated but the object didn't deleted.

I also tried:

```
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

right after step 3. The memory did not got deallocated.

Is there a way to cause core data to dealloc the memory after deletion?
And in general, is there a way to cause Core Data to keep those heavy objects as less as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the object reloads from the persistent store. Resetting removed from memory any changes you have made.

Both of these operations will "forget" the fact that you've deleted the object, since that change is only in memory.

You need to save the context after deleting.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. I edited the question.

Comment: Do you really save context BEFORE reset?

Comment: Note that I am using managed document witch is an abstraction layer above CoreData. sending save: to my managedObjectContext has no affect because it's a child context. I am investigating it now hope to post the answer soon...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently UIManagedDocument suppose to auto-save the changes and after that to give up the game pointers (causing IOS to dealloc the memory). UIManagedDocument auto save in it's own timing. This timing doesn't include the case above so the memory stayed around.
The workaround was to force UIDocument to save all changes to the persistent store by:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName = @"MyDocument";
NSURL *url = [documentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
[document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed in saveToURL");
    }
}];
```

After that, the memory deallocated!